# Flask decorator to set endpoint category

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and I am trying to use a decorator to set a category number (1 to 5) for various endpoints.
The value set needs to be accessible to a logging function I have defined and decorated with the blueprint's @bp.after_request

I want my endpoints to look like this:

```
@category(3)
@bp.route("/user")
def get_list_of_users():
    pass
```

My initial thought was to use the flask global context (g). To set a value g.category from within the decorator and then read it back from within the logging function.

I have coded the decorator like this:

```
def category(cat):
    def decorator(f):
        g.category = cat
        return f

    return decorator
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Working outside of application context.
```

I am not even sure if this is a good/standard approach for what I am trying to do. Any help or suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a one deeper definition:

```
def category(cat):
    "This function wraps original handler and takes category number into context"
    def decorator(f):
        "This function gets called during definition with original handler as f"
        def _f(*args,**kwargs):
            "This function gets called as your route handler would (by Flask)"
            g.category = cat
            return f(*args,**kwargs) # it calls the original function, passing args

        return _f

    return decorator
```

Comment: You beat me.. I had just worked it out but my solution used @wraps. I prefer yours. Thank you!